# Fixed div does not go beyond the screen's right edge

Tags: css, css-position

I have a `div` which has a `fixed` position. The problem is when the `div` moves to the right it does not go beyond the screen's right edge. It resizes itself making its width smaller. This does not happen when I give it a fixed `width`. But I want it to have a fluid width with `max-width` defined. I do not want it to stick to the right edge by defining `right`. I want to define the left position and let the excess go out of the screen.

You can see the problem here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BjZppJ

Click on the `div` in the example to see the problem.

**HTML CODE**

```
<div> -- RANDOM TEXT HERE -- </div>
```

**CSS CODE**

```
div
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
  background: rgba(112,66,102, .1);
}

div.right
{
  left: calc(100% - 300px)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Add `width: 100%;` to the div, by doing so it will always try to be 100% the width of it's parent, but since you set the max width, it will not quite get there.

```js
$('div').click(function(){
  
  if($(this).hasClass('right'))
  {
    $(this).removeClass('right')
  }
  else
  {
    $(this).addClass('right')
  }
     
  
})
```

```css
div
{
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  padding: 20px;
  max-width: 500px;
 background: rgba(112,66,102, .1);
  width: 100%;
}

div.right
{
  left: calc(100% - 300px)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>as dfas dfa sdf asdfasd fsdf sdfasdfa sdfasdfasd fasdfa sdfa sdfasdfa sdfasdfa sdfsdf sd</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

adding `width:100%` to the style definitions of the `div` will do the trick.

Default is `width:auto` and for elements with fixed positions it will try to calculate a width which does not overflow the window dimensions.