# How to make div extend to end of screen?

Tags: html, css

I used [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34724803/fixed-div-does-not-go-beyond-the-screens-right-edge) to make my `container` extend to the edge of the screen. However, there was still a white space (outlined in red):

[image]

So then I tried setting the `width` to `103.75%`. [But as I make the screen smaller the white space reappears.](http://im.ezgif.com/tmp/ezgif-2291846936.gif)

Is there a way to get the `container div`to fill that white space?

### My code

*HTML structure*

```
<div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="row-fluid">
            <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4">
            </div>
           <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="tab-content">
                    </div>
               </div>
           </div>
      </div>
</div>
```

*CSS*

```
.container{
    background-color: #86E1D8;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/14ongm/7ku7qvfx/)

Comment: If you are using Bootstrap 3 you do not need to use `.row-fluid`, `.row` will suffice.  This doesn't correct your alignment issue, but it will help bring your Bootstrap practices up to date.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a `no-padding` class and add it to `container-fluid` and the `col-sm-8` elements.

In the css add

`.no-padding{padding: 0;}`

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/1/

Comment: I don't think they want to strip all of the padding. They just want the right padding stripped.

Comment: I modified my answer to `.no-right-padding{ padding-right: 0;}`, but thanks! this was the solution that worked for me

Comment: Since you are not using clearfix with your .row-fluid, you will have problems with the floated elements. Use devtools and check row-fluid's height, it's equal to 0 when it should not. I suggest you address this @Adam.

Answer (score 1):

Removing the right padding on the div that wraps the container does what you want:

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8" style="padding-right: 0;">
  <div class="container">
<!-- ... -->
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7ku7qvfx/7/)

If you want it to expand both ways then remove the entire padding `padding: 0`.

What you can probably do is just create a helper class to do this for you:

```
.no-padding-right {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

And then use it where needed:

```
<div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 no-padding-right">
  <div class="container">
```

You can even override the default padding provided by these column classes, if you want this behavior to be universal:

```
.col-xs-7,
.col-sm-8 {
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The inner padding is not allowing your container to rest on the right margin. Adding these styles helped:

```
.container {
    position: relative;
    right: -30px; // 30 px padding from parents
}
```

Or you can remove the right padding of the parents:

```
.container-fluid {
    padding-right: 0;
}

.col-xs-7.col-sm-8 {
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: I would recommend removing the `.container` entirely; that class is reserved by Bootstrap and alterations to it will have sweeping effects.  Better to just use a new class for the teal background wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

**SOLUTION:**

First of all replace your `.row-fluid` class with `.row`. *(**EDIT**: Further explanation below.)*

Then create a class that will override Bootstrap's col-* default `padding-right: 15px` and `padding-left: 15px` and use it in your `div` element with `col-xs-7 col-sm-8`.

---

**CODE SNIPPET:**

```css
.container {
  background-color: #86E1D8;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}
.tab-content {
  background-color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 40%;
}
.col-no-padding {
  padding-left: 0;
  padding-right: 0;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<body>
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-5 col-sm-4">
        <div class="header">
          <h1>Problems</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
                                <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse1">Collapsible Group 1</a>
                            </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapse1" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <ul class="nav nav-pills">
                  <li class="active"><a data-toggle="pill" href="#home">H</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu1">11</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu2">22</a>
                  </li>
                  <li><a data-toggle="pill" href="#menu3">3</a>
                  </li>
                </ul>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse2">
        Collapsible Group 2</a>
      </h4> 
            </div>
            <div id="collapse2" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h4 class="panel-title">
        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapse3">
        Collapsible Group 3</a>
      </h4> 
            </div>
            <div id="collapse3" class="panel-collapse collapse">
              <div class="panel-body">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-xs-7 col-sm-8 col-no-padding">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
              <h3>HOME</h3>
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
              <h3>Menu 1</h3>
              <p>Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
              <h3>Menu 2</h3>
              <p>Sed ut perspiciatis unde omnis iste natus error sit voluptatem accusantium doloremque laudantium, totam rem aperiam.</p>
            </div>
            <div id="menu3" class="tab-pane fade">
              <h3>Menu 3</h3>
              <p>Eaque ipsa quae ab illo inventore veritatis et quasi architecto beatae vitae dicta sunt explicabo.</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

---

**FURTHER EXPLANATION:**

Since `.row` already uses clearfix for floated elements, you would need to replicate this behavior with something like this:

```
.row-fluid:after,
.row-fluid:before {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
```

Instead you can just use another class to remove row's default `margin-right: -15px;` and `margin-left: 15px;`

```
.row-no-margin {
  margin-left: 0;
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

---

*Side note:*

Make sure your external CSS file is referenced after Bootstrap's.